# How to get json response in rails api

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display all programmes which I got from a query as json response. I'm getting the programmes, but don't know how to render them through json. I'm using the `jbuilder` gem and created a `create.json.buider.rb` file. In my query I'm getting everything correctly, but I'm not receiving a JSON response with whatever details in I have in the query.

This is my controller. I have tried it like this but I'm not getting a json response. Only a status as 200.

```
class Api::V1::Categories::ProgrammesController < ApiController
  respond_to :json
  def category
    @category=Category.all
    @programmes=Programme.joins(:category).find_by(category_id: params[:category_id])
    if @programmes.present?
      render :json=> {:message=>"Programme not exists "}, :status=>422
    else
      render :json => @programmes
    end
  end
end
```

My `create.json.jbuilder` file:

```
json.programmes @programmes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change `@programmes` to `{ :programmers => @programmes.as_json }`

```
class Api::V1::Categories::ProgrammesController < ApiController
  def category
    @category = Category.all
    @programmes = Programme.joins(:category).find_by(category_id: params[:category_id])
    if @programmes.present?
      render :json=> {:message=>"Programme not exists "}, :status=>422
    else
      render :json => { :programmers => @programmes.as_json }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. thanks a lottt..  so haaapppyyyyyyyyyyyy